# CSS SASS if else if statement

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to use an else if in SASS?

Like this:

```
if(1+1 = 1) {

} else if(2+1=4) {

} else {

}
```

I have the following and it doesn't work:

```
$color: "blue", "green", "orange", "red", "pink", "grey", "black"

@for $i from 1 through length($color)
  .color-#{ nth($color, $i) }
    @if nth($color, $i) == "pink" or "grey"
      color: #f00
    @else if nth($color, $i) == "black"
      color: #0f0
    @else if nth($color, $i) == "orange"
      color: #000
    @else
      color: #fff
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the SASS reference:
[Yes, is it possible](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_8).

Even multiple times too:

SASS:

```
p 
  @if $type == ocean 
    color: blue
  @else if $type == matador
    color: red
  @else if $type == monster
    color: green
  @else
    color: black
```

SCSS:

```
p {
  @if $type == ocean {
    color: blue;
  } @else if $type == matador {
    color: red;
  } @else if $type == monster {
    color: green;
  } @else {
    color: black;
  }
```

Comment: I've updated the question, can you please check my problem?

Comment: I just edited the original answer. ;)

Comment: Because it isn't working on my case

Comment: Oh, I see now. I think you have a syntax error, but Im not sure. Please ty this: `.color-#{nth($color, $i)}`. Whitout the spaces the IDE (JetBrains WebStorm) is not highlights any problems, it should work.

Comment: It stays the same, I don't understand the difference

Comment: Try remove the quotation marks in the whole if statement. ;) I hope that will solve it for you. I have to admint I never used a statment like this.

Comment: It doesn't change even if I remove the quotation marks

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794220/use-array-value-as-variable